# Timed info popup frequency

Tags: popup, popover

I have a request for a info popup highlighting a button that can save a search. The idea is it popup pointing a the saved search button for 3 seconds.

My question is how often should this be done? My feeling is once it is cached in shouldn't repeat ever again unless the cookies are deleted?

Comment: Can the user close the popup? If so, then if the user closes it don't show it again.

Comment: Not in this case. It is like when you open a new app or webpage and you get those popups pointing out new features. I am trying to convince stakeholders this only needs to be seen once. Once it is detected in their cookies it doesn't need to be displayed again. They can be aggressive in that sense.

Comment: This would greatly annoy me.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to consider the user's needs. In general, it's important to strike a balance between providing helpful information and not overwhelming the user with too many popups or notifications.

One approach could be to only show the info popup the first time the user performs a search, not when you think they saw it. This would ensure that the user is aware of the saved search functionality, but wouldn't bother them with repeated popups and also avoids preemptively assuming the user saw the popup but they actually were just browsing around the app and happened to be on that page for a few seconds.

Another approach could be to show the info popup every time the user performs a search, but to include a checkbox or option (i.e. "Don't show again") for the user to disable the popup in the future if they don't find it helpful. This would allow the user to customize their experience and only see the info popup if they want to be reminded (e.g. they're just browsing now but they are interested in trying it out later and may forget about it).

Third approach would be to make it intelligent. Show it once, then if they do the same search a few times but have not used the feature, show it again to remind them until they adopt the feature.

Ultimately, the frequency of the info popup should be determined based on user testing and feedback to ensure that it is providing value to the user without being overly intrusive. Roll out the feature and track the adoption of "Saved search". Ideally, compare it to how many times users did the same search and how many of those came from loading a "Saved search".